# how to disable dates between two range materlizee css

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, materialize

I want to disable the date picker between two specific dates how to do that?? The issue is I cannot disable the dates between two specific dates like I want to disable from 2022-07-07 to 2022-07-28.

How do achieve this?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code

Comment: Please show some code and the date picker configuration you have!

Comment: Please provide a sample code for our better understanding